# Invariant subspaces of tensor product of SU(2)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Let $\varphi_n$ denote the standart irreducible representation of $SU(2)$ group with highest weight $n$.

I know that irreducible representations of $\varphi_2 \otimes \varphi_3 = \varphi_5 \oplus \varphi_3 \oplus \varphi_1$ (according to Clebsh-Gordan decomposition).

What will be the invariant subspace of $\varphi_2 \otimes \varphi_3$?

What will be the explicit form of the actions of irreducible reps on invariant subspaces?

Comment: Since there is no summand of the form $\phi_0$ in the decomposition of the tensor product you wrote, there is no invariant subspace (or, more precisely, the invariant subspace is zero)

Comment: As for the question in the last line, it does not make sense :-)

Comment: Do you want to find the individual summands, e.g. $\varphi_5,\varphi_3$ on the r.h.s? It seems to me that Mariano at least interprets "invariant subspace" as the subspace of elements that are fixed points for all the elements of $SU(2)$. I'm not sure whether I would call it `the subspace of invariants` or `the invariant subspace`, but don't quote me on that :-) I agree that for the question to make sense you are not referring to the subspace of fixed points. It is not unheard of to call any subrepresention an SU(2)-invariant subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working under the premise that you want to find, e.g. the submodule isomorphic to $\varphi_3$ inside the tensor product $\varphi_2\otimes\varphi_3$. Let the vectors
${\cal B}_2=\{x_0,x_1,x_2\}$ be a basis consisting of weight vectors of $\varphi_2$ (of respective weights 2,0,-2). Let similarly ${\cal B}_3=\{y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3\}$ be a basis of weight vectors of $\varphi_3$ (of respective weights 3,1,-1,-3). Then the space of vectors of weight three in the tensor product consists of the linear combinations
$$
a x_0\otimes y_1+bx_1\otimes y_0,
$$
where $a,b$ are arbitrary scalars. Calculate the effect of the raising operator (= a ladder operator that increases the weight) to such a linear combination. I dare not do that myself, because the details depend on how you normalized things and produced the bases ${\cal B}_2$ and ${\cal B}_3$ in the first place. You will find that - up to a scalar multiple - there is exactly one such linear combination that is annihilated by the ladder operator. That linear combination is then a high weight vector of weight three, and generates the copy $\varphi_3$.

You can similarly find (up to scalar multiple) a unique linear combination
$$
cx_0\otimes y_2+dx_1\otimes y_1+ex_2\otimes y_0
$$
of weight one vectors that is annihilated by the raising operator. Tha generates the remaining summand $\varphi_1$ inside $\varphi_2\otimes\varphi_2$.

Comment: could you suggest any literature on this theme?

Comment: I learned this stuff from [Humphreys](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algebras-Representation-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387900535). And apologies for having missed this request for 1½ years :-(